# Some websites for numerical values of orbit of $x$ under $f$ in a dynamical system

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, dynamical-systems

I don't know anything about programming. Is there some website to calculate the orbit of $x$ under $f$ in dynamical system?

For example, if $x_{n+1}=2x_n(1-x_n)$, how to a have a list of first many terms of ${\{x_n}\}$ without calculating one by one by calculator?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one website! [Here](http://www.calcul.com/show/calculator/recursive?values=[%7B%22n%22:1,%22value%22:0.999,%22valid%22:true%7D]&expression=2f(n-1)(1-f(n-1))&target=1&endTarget=50&range=true) it is.